# JQuery : Datepicker not centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using JQuery 1.8.17 and i am using the [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) from this. I have everything working as i want it functionally but for some reason the datepicker is not aligning to the center as the label for the datepicker is (i have added a border around the edge so you can see the text is centered but the datepicker is not

[image]

I would like the label and the datepicker to both be centered. Here is the code i am using

**JS**

```
$("#reportsStartDate").datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy",
             maxDate: -1,
             setDate: new Date(),
             onSelect: function (date) {
                 var date2 = $('#reportsStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
                 date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                 $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                 //sets minDate to reportsStartDate date + 1
                 $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
             }
         });

         $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy",
             maxDate: 0,
             onClose: function () {
                 var reportsStartDate = $('#reportsStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
                 console.log(reportsStartDate);
                 var reportsEndDate = $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker('getDate');
                 if (reportsEndDate <= reportsStartDate) {
                     var minDate = $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                     $('#reportsEndDate').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                 }
             }
         });
```

**HTML**

```
<span style="border-style: solid; border-width: medium;   display:inline-block; margin:0 auto;">

            Start Date:
            <input  type="date" id="reportsStartDate">

            End Date:
            <input type="date" id="reportsEndDate">

 </span>
```

Has anyone encountered this before or know what is going on as i cannot find a solution online anywhere?

**EDIT**

When i use

```
input{
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

nothing happens to the fields, but when i use

```
input{
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: I made a quick jsfiddle for his question  https://jsfiddle.net/yssg8mu6/ it seems fine to me, probably your issue in CSS, could you please provide us an example of CSS? Thanks

Comment: I have not added any CSS to the page, the only CSS i have is in the tags (e.g. style="border-style: solid;" ), could CSS outside the page be effecting this? ... sorry not great with front end technologies

Comment: if you HTML file link a CSS, that CSS could potentially change the style of your UI element.

Comment: i am loading JS files into the page but no CSS files

Comment: do you see properly the text in this https://jsfiddle.net/yssg8mu6/ ??

Comment: try using input {vertical-align:bottom;}

Comment: please see my edit above, using vertical-align:bottom did make changes but only to the text, not the datepickers

Comment: Try using line-height and height, as for my answer, let me know if it solves your problems :)

Comment: There is something in play causing this that you haven't included in your question. There is another style that is being inherited somewhere causing this. Could you add some of the code surrounding the span, and any styles that are being applied to those elements. Using what you have supplied doesn't match the problem in your image: http://jsfiddle.net/v5wzecdm/2/

Comment: I would also change your inputs to `type="text"`, because otherwise Google Chrome will add it's own date selector that doesn't have all the date options.

Comment: @JamieBarker : thanks, i have set this to "text" now

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height for your input in the following way (use the right dimension as for your layout).

Text will be aligned in the center vertically.

Quick example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yssg8mu6/3/

```
input{
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 60px;
    heightL 60px;

}
```

Comment: Whole date misaligned now in the css with the datepicker.

Comment: ok I understand, it is tricky to see what is your problem if we actually do not see your code... could you please create a jsfiddle reproducing your issue? we will have a look at it and provide you with some suggestions :)

Comment: thats the good idea to provide the code.

@Hip Hip Array: Can you provide the code or create the fiddle

Comment: im trying to create a JFiddle to reproduce the error at the moment but seems  to be working fine on JFiddle which to me seems like some other CSS file must be effecting this as if i dont use the !important code in my CSS blocks then no changes are registered on my page

Comment: Check the jquery UI-css file. and what properties are applying through it.